# In Django, how can I set db connection timeout?

Tags: python, database, django, caching, django-cache

OK, I know it's not that simple. I have two db connections defined in my settings.py: `default` and `cache`. I'm using `DatabaseCache` backend from `django.core.cache`. I have database router defined so I can use separate database/schema/table for my models and for cache. Perfect!

Now sometimes my cache DB is not available and there are two cases:

1. Connection to databse was established already when DB crashed - this is easy - I can use this recipe: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576780-timeout-for-nearly-any-callable/ and wrap my query like this:

   ```
   try:
       timelimited(TIMEOUT, self._meta.cache.get, cache_key))
   expect TimeLimitExprired:
       # live without cache
   ```
2. Connection to database wasn't yet established - so I need to wrap in `timelimited` some portion of code that actually establishes database connection. But I don't know where such  code exists and how to wrap it selectively (i.e. wrap only `cache` connection, leave `default` connection without timeout)

Do you know how to do point 2?

Please note, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1084571/940208 is not correct:

```
grep -R "connect_timeout" /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db
```

gives no results and cx_Oracle driver doesn't support this parameter as far as I know.

Comment: Are you using oracle as your db?

Comment: @MattWritesCode - if you haven’t notice, I included this link in my question saying this is not correct at all.

Comment: Please note that `oracle/base.py` do not modify connection settings (it only removes `use_returning_into` afair), as others backends do, so result of `grep` is predictable, yet `connect_timeout` will be passed as arg to `Database.connect`.

Comment: @alko - yes, I know it but in cx_Oracle documentation timeout parameter is not mentioned (strictly speaking it is in pool object but in very different meaning). Oracle philosophy is to set timeout on server not on client side so there is no client configuration that can define timeout.